# Select option goes beyond display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am using select tag to show a dropdown. in option tag i am doing       ng-repeat. if in that `ng-repeat`, there is a long string suppose of `maxlength=255`, how can i break into lines. because it overflows the screen.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IBDV.png)

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <select id="alert" name="alert" ng-model="dropdownSelectedRegion" ng-change="regionSelected(dropdownSelectedRegion)" class="admin-select-btn sans-regular-11 disposition" required>
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="{{region.id}}" ng-selected="dropdownSelectedRegion==region.id" ng-repeat='region in RegionList'>{{region.description | subStringFilter}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a complete piece of code. Also, please include **css** (and preferably **JS**) as well because it sounds like your solution should be solved in css

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can't do that with `html` to break, normally i set the title attribute to the `long text` and use a short `description` for my value.

```
<option value="1" title="Huge Description">your value</option>
```

Here is a fiddle found, which can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTs42/2/

Comment: I tried the same. But it does not work for dynamic data.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It is not working for me if i render dynamic data